# How to check all the URLs being hit while app is being build in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am getting the following Error while building android app

```
Cause: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I have figured out the issue is with my company network. The company network has blocked few URLs which is why it is not able to download the libraries. I want to know if there is any way to check all the URLs being hit while the app is being build. So I can gather all the URLs and send it to my IT team for whitelisting those URLs. I have tried adding certificates of the repositories to Android studio as well but it is still giving the same error. I have a mac machine if that is of any use.

```
> Could not resolve com.tealium:adidentifier:1.0.4.
 Required by:
     project :app
  > Could not resolve com.tealium:adidentifier:1.0.4.
     > Could not get resource 'https://maven.tealiumiq.com/android/releases/com/tealium/adidentifier/1.0.4/adidentifier-1.0.4.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://maven.tealiumiq.com/android/releases/com/tealium/adidentifier/1.0.4/adidentifier-1.0.4.pom'.
           > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
              > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```